# For which natural numbers $n ≥ 999$ is the number $N = \sqrt{n-999}+\sqrt{n+1000}$ natural?

Tags: perfect-numbers

*my question*

For which natural numbers $n ≥ 999$ is the number $N = \sqrt{n-999}+\sqrt{n+1000}$ natural?

*my idea*

[image]

[image]

I tried all the variants but it always gives that $n=999*1000$, which wont get $a$ and $b$ to be perfecr numbers

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text or formulas.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem), why. Use MathJax - here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This is answered (in principle) at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1769324p11602742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that in an analytics way.
We know that $n-999$ and $n+1000$ must be squares. So we have
$$
n - 999 = p^2 \text { for some } p \in\mathbb Z
$$
and
$$
n +1000 = q^2 \text { for some } q \in\mathbb Z.
$$
Let us write $n = p^2 + 999$ and use it in the other equation:
$$
p^2 + 999 + 1000 = q^2 \Leftrightarrow p^2 + 1999 = q^2.
$$
Now we can write
$
1999 = q^2-p^2
$
and that means, we are looking for the difference of two squares.
But since $1999$ is odd, there exists at least one.
And since it is even a prime, there exists exactly one, namely
$$
1999 = 1999\cdot 1 = (\frac{1999+1}{2})^2 - (\frac{1999-1}{2})^2 = 1000^2 - 999^2.
$$
So we have $q = 1000$ and $p = 999$ which leads to
$$
n = 999^2 + 999 = 999000.
$$
Indeed, since it is also
$$
n = 1000^2 - 1000 = 999000.
$$

And since there are no other solutions for the difference of two squares, this is the only solution for your question.

Answer (score 2):

$n=999000$ is a solution
$$\sqrt{999000+1000}+\sqrt{999000-999}$$
$$\sqrt{1000000}+\sqrt{998001}$$
$$1000+999$$
$$1999$$

I did what you did.

Comment: I believe you got stuck at the final step, when you tried solving for n